# onClick and action html

Tags: javascript, html

I am using purecss as a base for a simple project. What I am currently having trouble with is I have a submit button where I will pull some info from the fields, and when clicked I want to run some javascript, as well as take the user to another page. This is what I am trying with no luck:

```
    <div class="pure-controls">
        <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" onClick="saveInfo(this.form)" action="confirm.html">Submit</button>           
        <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Only `<form>` elements have an action attribute.

Comment: well how could I get the button to execute js and change pages too?

Comment: in saveInfo, you can set the document.forms[0].action="confirm.html" (assuming its the first form on the page). 

really, you should create an event listener that listens for thebutton click, and remove the entire inline stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your buttons IDs for simplicity, and take out that nasty inline JS.

```
<div class="pure-controls">
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id="button1">Submit</button>           
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id="button2">Search</button>
</div>
```

And then with your script:

```
var el = document.getElementById("button1"); //cache the save button
el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.forms[0].submit(); //submit the form or save it etc
    window.location.href = "confirm.html";
}, false); //event handler
```

Send your form data into the function, and then use a simple redirect since only form elements have action properties. Then just add the click event, save your form however you want (submission, ajax call, doesn't matter), then either in a callback or how it is, redirect the client with `window.location.href`

Comment: so do i put the bottom section of code(or something similar) inside of js tags somewhere? ive never really done web development so not sure about alot of things

Comment: You can run it via an external script, or wrap it in script tags at the bottom of the `<body>` tag. If you don't quite understand the code, look up every method I used. It might take some time, but it's good practice.

Comment: So if it is in js tags at the bottom of `<body>` i just call it whatever, but it doesn't actually need to be called? I'm familiar with event listeners (android/java swing). just checking though.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code inside `saveInfo()` redirect the user to `confirm.html` after you're done saving the info.

`window.location = "confirm.html"`

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Javascript event handler for a button press which might look something like:

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').onclick=function(){
    //Do whatever processing you need
    document.getElementById('formID').submit();
};
```

Alternatively, you could have an event handler in jQuery which would look something like:

```
$('#buttonID').on('click',function(){
    // Do whatever processing you need
    $('#formID').submit();
});
```

Comment: Please don't suggest jQuery unless the question is tagged as such, or the OP says they're open to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="pure-controls">
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id="button1">Submit</button>           
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id="button2">Search</button>
</div>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#button1').click(function(){
             var form = $(this).parents('form');

             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: $(this).attr('action'),
                 data: form.serialize(),
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(response) {
                      window.location.href = "http://www.page-2.com";
                 }
             });
             return false;
           });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form could as well do without a type submit.. 
Type can be a mere button.. On click, you could now do all your javascript stuff with onclick="javascript:somefunction()",

```
somefunction = function (){
Process javascript here 

document.formname.submit();

location.href = "new.html"

}
```